# Nativescript squeezes layout when keyboard appears (android)

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Using nativescript, when the user taps a input field and the keyboard appears, the whole layout gets 'squeezed', so my FAB button instead of being circular it gets squeezed. Setting a min-width/min-height doesn't seem to fix the problem... I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong with the layout or if it's a known issue. Looking around on Google I've found only posts about Java programming. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This is native Android related to viewgroups and layouts. It's not a simple fix :) but you can take an approach of hiding the FAB when the keyboard is visible. There is a plugin for detecting keyboard open/close activity which should be simple enough to toggle visibility. The reason the layout shifts tho can also be turned off in an Android apps manifest. The default is to shift the layout with a 'pan' type move so textviews are visible when keyboard opens. Those Java/android answers can be applied to your NS app

Comment: OMG What a honor getting an answer from @Brad Martin. Awesome work with that FAB button btw! Ok, so I get the point. I think I'll go with the plugin approach. Again, thank you.

Comment: No honor, just another coder who has no clue what I'm doing 99% of the time :) You should join the NS slack community, it's where you're going to find the best help, IMO as you move forward. https://developer.telerik.com/wp-login.php?action=slack-invitation Feel free to ping me on there also if you run into any road blocks.